# How use an async function in Vue v-if?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a service that control the permissions, is something like this:

```
//service
async function isAdmin(){
    let user = await getUser();
    //other stuff
    return isAdmin;//true|false
}

//in main
Vue.prototype.$service = permissions;

//component
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 v-if="$service.isAdmin()">You are Admin</h1>
    <h1 v-else>You aren't Admin</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried including this in async function in the component, and as computed property, but doesn't work (ever returns a `{}` true), and seems some ugly.

There is a way to manage this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The common practice to this kind of staff is to run the async operation in the mounted or created lifecycle hooks and update the data.
[Vue cookbook example for consuming data in async way.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <... v-if="isAdmin">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export defualt {
  data(){
   return {isAdmin : null}
  }, 
  created: async function(){
      this.isAdmin = await this.$service.isAdmin()
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: At final I added this as getter in vuex, but your example gave me an idea of how manage this. Anyway is helpful your code..